# java Constructor cannot be applied to given types android studio

Tags: java, android, constructor

I'm fairly new to java and I recently have been stuck on a problem, i keep getting the following error:

error: constructor User in class User cannot be applied to given types;
required: String
found: String,String,String,String
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

i have looked up similar issues but i cant seem to figure it out.

My constructor:

```
import org.w3c.dom.Node;

public class User {
    private String name,address,phoneNumber,emailAddress;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String name, String address, String phoneNumber, String emailAddress) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;

    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return emailAddress;
    }

    public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }
}
```

My activity calling the code

```
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                User user = new User(edt_name.getText().toString(),
                        edt_address.getText().toString(),
                        edt_email.getText().toString(),
                        phoneNumber);
```

[The error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UM4t3.png)
its meant to accept input into views and pass it to firebase.

Comment: The code seems correct. Did you clean and rebuild it? Are you importing the right user class?

Comment: Try cleaning your project. If it doesn't work, try File->Invalidate caches/restart. Your code seems correct. Android Studio sometimes bugs out and gives weird errors.

Comment: Please check `import org.w3c.dom.Node;` exist in android.

Comment: Btw, you're mismatching email and phone. The constructor needs the phone in the 3º position and the email in the last.

Comment: i have also tried invalidating and caching + placing email last but im still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Activity (the place where you're trying to construct `User` objects), you've imported a different `User` class. Find the `import com.incorrect.other.User` line and replace it with your own `import com.myapp.mycode.User`.

A clue to the fact that this is happening is that the screenshot shows that the `User` constructor is expecting to receive a `String uid`, but neither of the two constructors you've defined in your own `User` class metions a uid. So your activity must be referring to *some other* `User`, which means your imports are wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. this fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

you should place `phoneNumber` before `emailAdresse` :

```
 User user = new User(edt_name.getText().toString(),
                    edt_address.getText().toString(),
                    phoneNumber,
                    edt_email.getText().toString());
```

and please make sure `phoneNumer` is `string` and not `int`

Edit :

After i checked the image you posted later , your are not using your own `User` class ! make sure you are importing your own `User.class`

Comment: HI, thank you for the response, I have tried this and I'm still getting the exact same error, any other ideas?

Comment: did you check the user class are you working with ? make sure you imported your User class

Answer (score 0):

You're instantiating com.google.firebase.firestore.auth.User and not your own User class. You just need to correct your import or call yourpackage.User

Comment: Thank you so much, its was the mistake i was having Ben P explained it well.

Answer (score -2):

Create a function like createUser() in onClick function. Write your code in createUser() method. Hope it helps.